# the same equation on gcc or vs2022 have different result

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int y=2147483647;
    printf("%d\n",!(~y+~y));
}
```

When i compile it by gcc and run it in ubuntu, the result is 0.but when i compile and run it on vs2022,the result is 1. I can not understand how did the result of 0 come about.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Even without undefined behavior, why don't you understand the result of `0`? I don't understand how it could be `1`. Adding the same (non-zero) number will not result in `0`, so with the `!` in front, it will not be `1`,e.g., it must be `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bitwise inverse of decimal value `2147483647`/`0x7FFFFFFF` will end up as `0x80000000`. On a 2's complement system like yours, this is equivalent to `-2147483648`.

`-2147483648` + `-2147483648` gives an arithmetic underflow of `signed int`, it's undefined behavior and anything can happen. In practice, during optimization the compiler can either make the decision that `~y+~y` equals zero or that it equals non-zero, it's not well-defined.

Fix this by switching all types to `int64_t`/`PRIi64` (`#include <inttypes.h>`).